# How to have programmatically added icons the same size across different devices?

Tags: java, android

I have two devices and a fragment with an icon. This icon is added programmatically rather than in a layout XML file. On my two Android devices, this icon shows up as a completely different size (large on one, small on the other).

I suspected that this had to do with me specifying the dimensions in pixel length rather than dimension pixels (dp) like we usually do in layout XML files - so I wrote a method to convert pixels to dp:

```
public static float pixelsToDp(float pixels, Context context){
    return pixels / ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

So when using this method, the dimensions should be in terms of dp. Here is the code I use to add the icon:

```
private void addInfoIcon(Drawable infoIconDrawable) {
    // CONVERT PIXEL SIZE TO DP SIZE
    float infoIconSizeDp = AndroidUtils.pixelsToDp(INFO_ICON_SIZE_PX, getContext());
    final ImageView ivInfoIcon = new ImageView(getContext());
    ivInfoIcon.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int) infoIconSizeDp, (int) infoIconSizeDp));
    ivInfoIcon.setBackground(infoIconDrawable);

    rlInfo.addView(ivInfoIcon);
}
```

This didn't seem to help - the icon on both devices has gotten smaller (as expected) but still different sizes.

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any insight :)

Comment: Are you need these icons on different devices (different density) in the same size in pixels, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to convert `dp` to `px`, not the other way around; most Android functions accept `px` values and we're used to thinking about dimensions in terms of `dp`. For example, normally you'd specify `36dp` in a layout file, but `LayoutParams` needs its arguments to use px units, so you need to convert 36 dp into some unknown number of px.

The correct method to convert `dp` to `px` would be this:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context context){
    return (int) (dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

However, an even better approach would be to create a `dimen` resource and access that. Doing this means that the system will automatically perform the dp-to-px conversion for you! Plus, then you can continue to use the notation you're familiar with (e.g. `36dp`), *and* you can change it and re-launch the app very quickly because no Java code needs to be recompiled.

Additionally, you generally want to set the image of an `ImageView` to be the view's "source", not the view's "background" (corresponding to `android:src` instead of `android:background`).

Put together, I'd use this:

- `res/values/dimens.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="info_icon_size">36dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

- your java file:

```
private void addInfoIcon(Drawable infoIconDrawable) {
    int infoIconSizePx = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.info_icon_size);
    final ImageView ivInfoIcon = new ImageView(getContext());
    ivInfoIcon.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(infoIconSizePx, infoIconSizePx));
    ivInfoIcon.setImageDrawable(infoIconDrawable);

    rlInfo.addView(ivInfoIcon);
}
```